# Nested lambda expression translated from SQL statement

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, lambda

Using lambda expressions, how do you translate this query?

```
select * from employee where emp_id=1 and dep_id in (1,2,3,4).
```

I am trying this expression but this results in exceptions:

```
public IEnumrable<employees> getemployee(int emp,list<int> dep )
{
_employeeService.GetAll(e=>(e.emp_id=emp||emp==null) && (e.dep_id.where(dep.contains(e.dep_id))|| dep.count==0 )
}
```

Any suggestion for translating these queries to these lambda expressions?
wahts wrong in these function?

Comment: It is resulting in an exception? Really? Any details?

Comment: @Shmandor, you can't just repost your questions if someone doesn't answer.  Why don't you delete this one and try to rephrase (change the words) the older one (only 4 hours and already reposting!?) so that people can answer.

Comment: @Cpfohl no Duplicate occurs i need to write these function correctly

Comment: @shmandor: you posted the same question three times.  You should delete all the questions except one, and in that question copy the exceptions you are getting and give as many details as possible.  (If English is not your first language try Google Translate).

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but it's pretty spammy.  @shmandor: consider reading up on some LINQ basics and marking some answers - or [reading the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you're not sure what that means.

Comment: @ladenedge, man, I could barely tell the difference, you're right though, they are different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to sound patronizing, but I'd suggest you pick up a beginner's C# book before going further.  You've made errors in basic syntax such as operator precedence and equality comparison.
Also, remember that primitive data types cannot be checked for null, unless they're explicitly specified as nullable. In your case emp would be of type int?,not int. 
 Meanwhile, try

```
_employeeService.Where(e=>(e.emp_id==emp) && (dep == null || dep.contains(e.dep_id)) );
```